# Importing Files csv from Folder into single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I was using below code to get the multiple CSV files into single sheet.

code is working fine but the issue is that, it should not copy the headers of each file, because  each file header is same.

Code should copy the first file header not all files.

One more thing that i do not want first column to copy all sheets name i have tried to remove that filed but code does not work.

Can i get any help.
thanks

```
Sub CSV()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xFile As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.csv")
Do While xFile <> ""
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
xWb.Close False
xFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox "no files csv", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I did two attempts, first one untested, and did it on my phone:

```
Sub CSV()
    Dim xSht As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.csv")
    Dim counter as Long
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        Dim sourceRange as Range
        Set sourceRange = xWb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        If counter = 0 then
            sourceRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        else
            sourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1, sourceRange.Columns.Count).Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            
        End If
        xWb.Close False
        xFile = Dir
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
    ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files csv", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Second attempt from my computer, I refactored the code handled first file case, skipped the clipboard and use proper procedure and variable names.

```
Public Sub ImportAndAppendCSVFromFolder()

    ' Set basic error handling
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    ' Turn off stuff
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim xSht As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    
    ' Prepare and display file dialog to user
    Dim customFileDialog As FileDialog
    Set customFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    customFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    customFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    
    ' Get folder path from file dialog
    If customFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        Dim folderPath As String
        folderPath = customFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
    ' Exit if nothing was selected
    If folderPath = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Set reference to active sheet (could be replaced to a specific sheet name with this: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName") )
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Get files in directory ending with specific extension
    Dim sourceFile As String
    sourceFile = Dir(folderPath & "\" & "*.csv")
    
    ' Loop through files
    Do While sourceFile <> ""
        
        ' Open file
        Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & sourceFile)
        
        ' Set reference to sheet in file (as it's a csv file, it only has one worksheet)
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        

        ' Depending if it's the first file, include headers or not
        Dim counter As Long
        If counter = 0 Then
            ' Set reference to used range in source file
            Dim sourceRange As Range
            Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.UsedRange
            ' Calc offset if it's first file
            Dim rowOffset As Long
            rowOffset = 0
        Else
            ' Don't include headers in range
            Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, sourceSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
            ' Calc offset if it's not first file
            rowOffset = 1
        End If
    
        ' Perform copy (as this comes from a csv file, we can skip the clipboard
        targetSheet.Range("A" & targetSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, sourceRange.Columns.Count).Offset(rowOffset).Value2 = sourceRange.Value2

        ' Close csv file
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Get reference to next file
        sourceFile = Dir
        
        counter = counter + 1
    
    Loop

CleanExit:
    ' Turn on stuff again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Exit Sub
    
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "An error occurred:" & Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Ricardo Diaz, Thank you so much Sir.