# Excel VBA import files from file path

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm using this code to import excel files from a given path.

I want to add the Get Sheets to my Personal Macro Workbook. I'd like to add a pop up box when selecting the GetSheets macro where i can paste in the file pathing.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciate?

```
Sub GetSheets()
'Paste filepath of folder in the "" and end with \
Path = "C:\\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
    DoEvents
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: IIUC, research a "folder picker." Lots of examples on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65321656/1521579)